# Trying to send email using python and getting below timeout error

Tags: python, ssl, smtplib

```
import smtplib as sm
import ssl as s

host = "smtp.gmail.com"
port = 465

username1 = "xxxxxxxx@gmail.com"
password1 = "xxxxxxxxxx"

msg = """\\
Subject: Test Mail
Sending from Python
"""

receiver1 = "xxxxxxxx@gmail.com"

my_context = s.create_default_context()

with sm.SMTP_SSL(host, port, context=my_context) as connection:
    connection.login(username1, password1)
    connection.sendmail(username1, receiver1, msg)
```

Trying to send out email to other receiver but getting timeout error with below reason.
'TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond'

Comment: Try this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/send-mail-from-your-gmail-account-using-python . It seems SMTP lib has its own TLS implementation.

Comment: In short: the code is fine. But something in your network is blocking access. Nothing is known about your environment though.